# Remove custom registration form on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a [modal login](http://codecanyon.net/item/modal-log-in-for-wordpress/3509483) plugin and I need to stop the registration form from appearing when people click register on my Wordpress site. I only wan't to use the modal login for logging into my site.
I already have the redirect setup so that when people click on register it goes to a custom page but since installing the modal plugin, the modal registration form takes over.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-modal-login/ ? Which plugin is it?

Comment: No. I'm using Modal Log In for Wordpress which is very customizable with a css editor that has a very nice GUI: http://codecanyon.net/item/modal-log-in-for-wordpress/3509483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In admin panel **Administration** > **Options** > **General**

Membership

- `Anyone can register` => Check this checkbox if you want anyone to be able to register an account on your blog.

This will disable your registration.

**Alternative:**

You can use [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ag-custom-admin/) plugin. You can change register link to login link by using this plugin

Comment: Hi there, I don't want to disable registration. I just want to stop the modal from popping up when people click "register"

Comment: I think, you need to get support for this from item owner http://codecanyon.net/item/modal-log-in-for-wordpress/3509483. An overriding operation needed for your case